Adding multiples style classes with `:::` operator in Mermaid diagram
Mermaid's documentation gives an example of ::: operator to attribute a class to a node :
flowchart LR
    A:::foo
    classDef foo stroke:#f00

But how do you attribute two classes to a node with the same syntax ? Something like :
flowchart LR
    A:::foo,bar
    classDef foo stroke:#f00
    classDef bar fill:#0f0

Which doesn't work. For now, I use
class A foo
class A bar

